# pdf.js AcroForms properties

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am experimenting with pdf.js and I think I found a bug. The JavaScript code I am running is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="pdf.js"></script>
<script src="pdf.worker.js"></script>
<body>

<script>

function renderPage(page)
{
    page.getAnnotations().then(function(items)
    {
        for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
        {
            console.log(items[i].fieldName);
            console.log(items[i].fieldType);
            if (items[i].fieldType == 'Ch')
            {
                console.log(items[i].fieldValue[0]);
                console.log(items[i].options.length);
                for (var j = 0; j < items[i].options.length; j++)
                {
                    console.log(items[i].options[j].displayValue);
                    console.log(items[i].options[j].exportValue);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function renderPages(pdfDoc) 
{
    for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
}

PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
PDFJS.getDocument('ComboBox.pdf').then(renderPages);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code basically enumerates all AcroForms on a given pdf document plus, if the AcroForm is a ComboBox, the list of values.

Code works fine if there if any given ComboBox is present only once in the document. However, if a ComboBox is duplicated (and this is allowed by Acrobat), then «options.length» always returns 0.

I am using the latest beta (1.7.225) of pdf.js.

I submitted the issue on GitHub.

Comment: Can you please add some more code to your question? It's always helpful if it is easy to reproduce or at least look at some code in context.

Comment: Writing a tiny piece of code helped me pinpoint the problem and I just edited my post. Thanks Christoph for reminding me that small things matter!

Comment: Glad I could help:-) If anything happens that helps solving your problem (when the issue is fixed), feel free to write a short answer and accept it, so we know your problem is solved!